# Can't Access Ubuntu Server on any Computer on Same Network After Enabling SSH

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh

On my Ubuntu Server, I recently added a static IP address, installed the LAMP-Stack and openssh to allow SSHing into the server.  However, recently I have noticed that any computer that is on the same network as the server, is getting blocked from accesing the website, or SFTP/SSH.  Any other computer outside is completely fine.

Any ideas?  I saw some threads that mentioned this could be an internal/external IP address issue, but I didn't find any solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On each system can you `ip address show;ip route show;ip neighbor show`? What is your WiFi router make and model#? Is configured to act as a "hub"?

Comment: Thanks!  When I run that command, what should I be looking for when I compare the results between the different devices?